# Underline and bold round number in table

Tags: tables, formatting

I use `numprint` package to round number in table. I want to bold, underline, etc., some round numbers, but the following is not working

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint} 
\begin{document}

\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}
\begin{tabular}{n{5}{2}}
0.123456 \\
\textbf{0.123456} \\ 
%\npboldmath 0.1234562 \\ % Not working undefined control sequence \npboldmath
\underline{0.123456} 
\end{tabular}
\npnoround

\end{document}
```

The output is

```
0.12 
0.123456
0.123456
```

I read in numprint documentation that `\npboldmath` should be used for bolding, but this is also not working (commented line).

Comment: The [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/numprint/numprint.pdf) (p 11) clearly states that `\npboldmath` is only available when including `numprint` with the [boldmath]` package option (for memory conservation purposes). Also, you'll have to use `{\npboldmath} 0.1234562`.

Comment: @Werner Thank you, `{\npboldmath}` works. Do you know how to solve problem with underline, it should be 0.12 underline (0.12 as round of 0.123456), not 0.123456 underline. The answer bellow does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the numprint manual:

```
If you also want to use that font in math mode, you may use the math version 
npbold by using \mathversion{npbold} or \npboldmath. In order to save memory, 
these commands and the npbold math version are only available if you call 
numprint.sty using the boldmath package option.
```

So you just need to use `\usepackage[boldmath]{numprint}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boldmath]{numprint}
\begin{document}

\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}
\begin{tabular}{n{5}{2}}
0.123456 \\
\textbf{0.123456} \\
{\npboldmath}0.1234562 \\ % Now working
\underline{\numprint{0.123456}}
\end{tabular}
\npnoround

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Note that the use of `\npboldmath` is a little strange: you need to put it inside braces before the number. If you want to apply formatting like `\underline` then you need to explicitly put `\numprint` inside this. If you are doing this often you might want to define a macro like:

```
\newcommand\Underline[1]{\underline{\numprint{#1}}
```

The same comment applies when using `\textbf` -- although you probably should be using `\mathbf` above. That is,

```
$\mathbf{\numprint{0.123456}}$
```

produces **0.12**.

Comment: Tnx for this. But the main problem is I need to get 0.12 in all lines, (0.12 underline), and the rounding number not works if the numbers is formated.

Comment: @Petar I've edited my answer so that it also addresses the rounding problem.